# HTML table adding extra th

Tags: html

Ok, I have been looking at this code and I cannot figure why its adding duplicate th's. The table data is not adding any extra td, so I am kinda stumped. Could this be due to missing an element somewhere? I am not thinking that my PHP code is affecting it in anyway.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php

//header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excel.xls");

include('queries.php');
$role = $_POST["role"];
$menu = $_POST["menu"];


$tests = getTestCases($role, $menu);
?>
<form action="testCaseToExcel.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Download to Excel" />
</form>
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Role<th>
    <th>Path<th>
    <th>Link<th>
    <th>Link Type<th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
    foreach ($tests as $test) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $test->role;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $test->path;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $test->link_name;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $test->link_type;?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
?>
</table>
<form action="testCaseToExcel.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Download to Excel" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you didn't close any of your th tags like </th> not <th> ...

Comment: see with properly closed tags it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aHRtE/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to close any of your `<th>` tags. Should be:

```
<tr>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Path</th>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Link Type</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: @jrock2004: A decent IDE would solve these kinds of problems before they happen.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are making a html syntax error

```
<tr>
    <th>Role<th>
    <th>Path<th>
    <th>Link<th>
    <th>Link Type<th>
</tr>
```

in your code make the following change
i think you should use closing tags for the header tabs , see it might help

```
<tr>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Path</th>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Link Type</th>
</tr>
```